# C# in WPF: DispatcherTimer - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-phone-8, timer, windows-phone

I am trying to implement a timeout for my webclient. All that the client is doing is checking if there is a connection to a server. That part works fine, but by default does not timeout. That's why I am trying to implement a timer which cancels the Async-call. Here is the code:

```
namespace WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands
{
    public class BasicAuth : BaseCommand
    {
        //Create timer to control timeout
        DispatcherTimer timeoutTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    public void get(string options)
    {
        //Parse data that gets passed into the plugin
        string[] passedData = JSON.JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options);

        //save data to variables

        try
        {
            //Set interval for timer, add event handler and start timer
            timeoutTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            timeoutTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timeout);
            timeoutTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
        try
        {
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
            //Define credentials, set header etc.
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Catch exception and react
        }
    }

    void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try{
            //Do stuff
        } catch{
            //Do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
            timeoutTimer.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void timeout(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeoutTimer.Stop(); //Stop timer from beeing executed again
        webClient.CancelAsync(); //Cancel Async download
        //handle timeout
    }
}
```

}

So the idea is to start a timer and if that timer ticks for the first time (after 5 seconds in this case) stop the timer, cancel the Async-part and handle the timeout.
Unfortunately all I get is the following Exception when I create the timer:

> An Exception (first chance) of type "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" occured in mscorlib.ni.dll.
>
> An Exception (first chance) of type "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" occured in System.Windows.ni.dll.
>
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.
>
> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
>
> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, String s)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.set_Interval(TimeSpan value)
>
> at WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands.BasicAuth.get(String options)

I haven't really worked with C# before, so there might be a simpler or better solution for it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion based on the exception messages. Try to avoid setting timeoutTimer's properties in the get method. If possible, create a parameterless constructor for BasicAuth and move these lines there

```
timeoutTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
timeoutTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timeout);
```

A bit guessing, but hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

har07-tip fixed the problem.

It indeed seemed to work better to place those two lines plus the starting of the timer in a constructor. Also the canceling the Async-part is actually handled by the event handler of my DownloadString method. I stop the timer already in the timeout-method and than again in the webClient_DownloadStringCompleted-method.

Since the timer was stopped here already, it raised an exception. I introtuced a additional boolean to see where I was comming from and acting accordingly.